# Fill Angular form with @Input with data that is inyected with service and that comes from a firebase db

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I've been struggling with some problem in Ionic Angular with a form.
I have a component that is basically a form that is filled by a Input (Component).

The thing is that it seems that the forms it gets filled before the data gets to the input field.
That data came from a service which is inyected in a father component.
I would like to display the data that is comming from the service instead the object in Component. The data that comes from the service is "Jack" but it shows me "John".

Thanks!

**HTML Component**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-item button="true" detail="false">
      <ion-input  label="Name"
                  formControlName="userName"
                  placeholder="Enter Name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
export class EventoComponent  implements OnInit {

  @Input() users: Atencion[] = [{
    userName: 'John'
  }];

  public myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    userName: [this.users[0].userName]
  })

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

}
```

**Father Component:**

```
export class EventoPage implements OnInit {
  
  users: Atencion[] = [];
  

  constructor(private dataService: GetDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getUsersData()
      .subscribe( users => {
      this.users.push(users);
    });

  }

}
```

I'm trying to fill the forms with an input, that is previosly filled by a service

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Please update your question with the code as text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

use a setter in input.

```
public myForm!:FormGroup
public users:Atencion[] //<--see if really you need
@Input('users') set _users(value:Atencion[]){
    this.users=value;
    this.myForm= this.fb.group({
       userName: [value[0].userName]
    });
}
```

Or, using setValue in the setter

```
  users: Atencion[] = [{
    userName: 'John'
  }];

  public myForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    userName: [this.users[0].userName]
  })

    @Input('users') set _users(value:Atencion[]){
        this.users=value;
        this.myForm.controls.userName.setValue(value[0].userName)
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo!! I'm kind of new here! So thanks!!